# Run a periodic task in background independent from viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I'm not sure exactly how to correctly construct my question. It is actually more of a "what is the advised practice" instead of an "how to" type of question.  So I'll try to explain my main goal first.

I've started writing a small app which allows users to fill out forms and send them to a server. But the connectivity is a real problem. Often there are times that these filled out forms must be saved on the device until wi-fi is available again.

The app has multiple view controllers, each with different jobs as you can imagine. I am thinking of writing a class which will be initialized during the app launch and will continue to run through out the apps whole life cycle. This class will periodically check for an internet connection and when available, upload saved forms to the server and than remove them from local core data database.

I've read about the background tasks, singletons, app delegate functions, global functions etc. And honestly I am confused. Every article and/or post I've read criticizes the other method with no one noting the correct way of doing this. "Globals are bad", "singletons are evil", "don't use app delegate" etc... I'm not sure what is the advised practice to achieve this.

Can we please discuss what is the preferred way to write a "self contained, periodic check and upload function" which is independent from any viewcontroller and will run in the background during apps whole life cycle.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good use-case for a singleton to me. Don't let the haters get you down. Sure, singletons can be bad if you have a bunch of them, or if they grow too large and do too many different things, but like you said: "initialized during app launch," "self-contained," "independent." That sounds like a singleton.

Comment: you need not have a class that would check for the internet state through out the life cycle of app, you have Reachability classes that does that job for you and informs your viewControllers about the change of state of internet. My idea create a singleton class, add it as observer to Reachability classes, everytime network state changes to available start webservice call to upload data by reading data from core data. Whether to use singleton or not, shall we put code in app deleagte or not is a personal opinion and might vary from developer to developer. Nothings bad if u know how to use it

Comment: People often express their loyalty to certain design pattern by criticizing other patterns without realising design patterns are nothing more than tried n tested way to solve commonly faced problems in coding n no single design pattern solves all the problems in coding world alone. Design pattern effective to your problem might not be effective to somebody with a slightly different problem. What is correct n what is wrong can only be judged by u once u decide to go ahead with any one of them u choose. There only 2 possible outcomes either u succeed or will learn a lesson about the pattern :)

Comment: This question is probably opinion-based, so I will answer in a comment; A singleton is not a bad approach to this, but the main drawback of singletons is that they can make testing difficult as you can't mock them easily.  An object instance held as a property on the app delegate is probably a good compromise; It is easily accessible from anywhere in your app since `UIApplication` is a singleton and you can still mock the object for testing if you want.